# The correct way of implementing adblocking with uzbl?

Tags: proxy, browser, hosts, netfilter, adblock

I though about running some proxy on localhost, but will I be able to filter https? I've tried to use scripts from wiki, but they are not seem to work.

Another idea is to implement adblocking using /etc/hosts It is workable and not too severe? Won't it cripple useful features?